# Symfony 4 Cannot inject scalar value on Service

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I have the ff class:

```
namespace App\Component\Notification\RealTimeNotification;

use App\Component\Notification\NotificationInterface;

class EmailNotification implements NotificationInterface
{   
    private $logNotification;
    private $mailer;
    private $engine;

    // This will appear on From field on Email.
    private $mailerFrom;

    public function __construct(LogNotification $logNotification, \Swift_Mailer $mailer, \Twig_Environment $twig, string $from)
    {
        $this->logNotification = $logNotification;
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
        $this->twig = $twig;

        $this->mailerFrom = $mailerFrom;
    }

    public function send(array $options): void
    {   
        // Resolve options
        $this->resolveOptions($options);

        $sendTo = $options['sendTo'];
        $subject = $options['subject'];

        $template = $options['template'];
        $data = $options['data'];
        $body = $this->createTemplate($template, $data);

        $this->sendEmail($sendTo, $subject, $body);
    }

    protected function sendEmail($sendTo, $subject, $body): void
    {
        dump($this->mailerFrom);
        $message = (new \Swift_Message())
            ->setSubject($subject)
            ->setFrom($this->mailerFrom)
            ->setTo($sendTo)
            ->setBody($body, 'text/html')
        ;

        $this->mailer->send($message);
    }

    protected function createTemplate($template, $data): string
    {
        return $this->twig->render($template, $data);
    }

    protected function resolveOptions(array $options): void
    {

    }

    protected function createLog(array $email): void
    {
        $message = 'Email has been sent to: ' . $email;

        $this->logNotification->send([
            'message' => $message,
        ]);
    }
}
```

I tried to manually wire all the arguments with the following:

```
# Notification
app.log_notification:
    class: App\Component\Notification\RealTimeNotification\LogNotification

app.email_notification:
    class: App\Component\Notification\RealTimeNotification\EmailNotification
    decorates: app.log_notification
    decoration_inner_name: app.log_notification.inner
    arguments:
        $logNotification: '@app.log_notification.inner'
        $mailer: '@mailer'
        $twig: '@twig'
        $from: '%mailer_from%'
```

However, when I run the app it throws the exception:

> Cannot autowire service
>   "App\Component\Notification\RealTimeNotification\EmailNotification":
>   argument "$from" of method "__construct()" must have a type-hint or be
>   given a value explicitly

Why is this event happening?

Thanks!

Comment: It's because you are trying to inject your EmailNotification into yet another service using a typehint against EmailNotification.  So autowire is looking in the container for a service id matching the class name.  It won't automatically use app.email_notification.  So it tries to make a new service and fails on the scalar.  If you are using autowire then you no longer need service ids such as app.email_notification.  Just use the class name.  And if you really want to keep you id then add an alias.  It's all documented.  Also a bunch of questions on the exact same topic.

Comment: @Cerad, you are actually right. That's the way i did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Answer by @Matteo is great! You can even drop service definition and delegate to [parameter binding](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-4-local-service-binding) **since Smyfony 3.4+/2018+**:

```
 # config/services.yaml
 services:
     _defaults:
         bind:
             $adminEmail: 'manager@example.com'

     # same as before
     App\:
         resource: '../src/*'
```

Do you want more example and logic behind it? Find it here: https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2018/01/22/how-to-get-parameter-in-symfony-controller-the-clean-way/#change-the-config

Comment: I dont need to use app.email_notification but instead use the fully qualified class name.

Comment: It is, no argument here. This is just way to take it even further to less writing. You can use directly typehint, yes. Named service are not needed since Symfony 2.8 and autowiring.

Answer (score 0):

Autowiring only works when your argument is an object. But if you have a scalar argument (e.g. a string), this cannot be autowired: Symfony will throw a clear exception.

You should [Manually Wiring Arguments](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#services-manually-wire-args) and explicitly configure the service, as example:

```
# config/services.yaml
services:
    # ...

    # same as before
    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{Entity,Migrations,Tests}'

    # explicitly configure the service
    App\Updates\SiteUpdateManager:
        arguments:
            $adminEmail: 'manager@example.com'
```

> Thanks to this, the container will pass manager@example.com to the
>   $adminEmail argument of __construct when creating the
>   SiteUpdateManager service. The other arguments will still be
>   autowired.

Hope this help